# Condition on $u$ so that $ |\frac{x \cdot u } {u \cdot u}u - x |< |x|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $u,x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then am I right to assert that the above inequality will hold if $u$ makes an angle $\alpha \in (0,\pi/2)$ with span$\{x\}^{\perp}$?

When $n=3$ it seems quite apparent that $|\frac{x \cdot u } {u \cdot u}u - x | = \cos(\alpha)|x|<|x|.$ I think it's exactly the same in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The expression only makes sense when $u \neq 0$, and then $\hat{u} := \frac{x \cdot u}{u \cdot u} u$ is the projection of $x$ onto $u$, i.e. $\hat{u}$ is parallel to $u$ and $x = v + \hat{u}$ such that $v \cdot u = v \cdot \hat{u} =0$.

Consequently, $|\frac{x \cdot u}{u \cdot u} u - x| = | v | < |\hat{u} +v| = |x|$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks but in particular the quantity does depend on angle $\alpha$ that $u$ makes with the orthogonal complement of span$\{x\}$, right?

Comment: The quantity does, but the inequality is always true. In fact, you wrote almost the right thing in your question, except that it should have been $\sin (\alpha)$ rather than $\cos (\alpha)$: e.g. when $u=x$ the expression is just zero.

Comment: $\alpha$ is the angle $u$ makes with span$\{x\}^{\perp}$ though not $x$, which is $\pi/2$ if $u=x$.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, I read that wrong.